# Using Stratified Kfold within Pipeline

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to impute some data and scale it, then search for the best set of hyper params of my model (Random Forest and Logistic Regression Classifier) using cross-validation. Also, I want to wrap whole thing into a Pipeline.

for now I use this code:

```
param_grid = [{'solver':['liblinear',],
           'Cs':[5, 10], 'penalty':['l1','l2'], 
           'tol':[0.1, 0.001, 0.0001],
           'max_iter':[50,100,200]},
      {'solver':['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'sag'],
       'Cs':[5, 10,], 'penalty':['l2'], 
       'tol':[0.1, 0.001, 0.0001],
       'max_iter':[50,100,200]}
       ]

clf = LogisticRegressionCV()
grid = GridSearchCV( estimator=clf, param_grid = param_grid)

pipe = Pipeline([('impute', Imputer(strategy='mean', axis=1)),
             ('scale', StandardScaler()),
             ('grid', grid_search)])

cv = StratifiedKFold(Ytrain, n_folds = 5, shuffle=True, random_state=2016)

score = cross_val_score(pipe, Xtrain, Ytrain, cv=cv)
print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.5f})".format(np.mean(score),np.std(score)))
```

However, I have a feeling that this way data scaling and imputation happens globally, which is not correct. How can I apply kfolding first, then imputation and scaling to each part separately, and then perform model fit?

Comment: I think that you are using the correct approach. What do you mean "globally"? The imputer and scaler will be reinitialised for each fold of the cross validation.